# Express Generator app.use('/login', users) not picking up routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I used express generator and am confused as to why I cannot use the users.js routes file for my login routes.

I created the POST route below and if I leave it in app.js it works fine. However, if I move it into users.js and try to use

```
app.use('/login', users)
```

where users is :

```
var users = require('./routes/users');
```

from app.js to reference it, I get errors that there is no post route to /login. Why does this happen ?

```
app.post('/login', function(req,res) {
  var user = req.body.user;

  db.User
    .authenticate(user.email, user.password)
    .then(function (user) {

          req.login(user);

          res.redirect("/"); // redirect to user profile
      });
});
```

Comment: Are you exporting anything?

Comment: It is the express generator generated file. So, module.exports = router; is at the bottom of the file by default

Comment: also note, if I change app to router, so that the route is router.post('/login', function(req,res) {.........I still get POST /login 404 26.854 ms - 1891

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mounting a router that handles `/login` to the path `/login`.

This results in the URL `/login/login`.

You probably want to make the inner router handle `/`.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out but that was indeed the problem!